# Deterministically finding $g$ such that $f(g(x)) \ge x$?

Tags: logic, solution-verification, conjectures

It's just some random thoughts, but I find it confusing.

Here's the classical "prove" that every natural number can be described within eleven words:

> Suppose not, then there's a smallest counterexample $n$. Then $n$ can be described as "the smallest natural number that cannot be described within eleven words", which is itself in eleven words, contradiction.

Of course, the proof above is false. But when I tried to do the same thing mathematically, something confusing happened. Suppose $f$ is an arbitrary injective function $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$. Let $h$ be a bijection from "all finite logical formula" to $\mathbb{N}$. Let $\varphi_n$ denote the formula with $f(h(\varphi_n))=n$. For some $M \in \mathbb{N}$ let $p \in \mathbb{N}$ such that

$$\varphi_p(x) = \neg\exists m\in\mathbb{N}(m<M \wedge \varphi_m(x) \wedge \neg\exists y\in\mathbb{N}(\varphi_m(y))) \wedge\\ \forall y\in\mathbb{N}(y<x \to \exists m\in\mathbb{N}(m<M \wedge \varphi_m(y) \wedge \neg\exists z\in\mathbb{N}(\varphi_m(z))))$$

($x$ is the smallest natural number such that there is no formula $\varphi_m$ with $m<M$ such that $\varphi_m$ "accurately describes" $x$, i.e. $x$ is the only natural number that satisfies $\varphi_m$.)

Let us first assume that $p < M$. If there is an $y \in \mathbb{N}$ that $\neg\exists m\in\mathbb{N}(m<M \wedge \varphi_m(y))$, let $y$ be the smallest such number. Then $\varphi_p(y)$, but $p < M$, contradiction! Therefore every natural number can be accurately described with some formula $\varphi_m$ with $m<M$, but the number of such formula is finite, contradiction! So $p \ge M$.

What does this mean? We have found, constructively, a function $h^{-1} \circ p: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ injective, such that $f(h(h^{-1}(p(M)))) \ge M$ which is $f(p(M)) \ge M$, for every $M$. This is very counter-intuitive, since such a $p$ is usually found inductively.

Is there something wrong in the above construction?

Comment: "Constructive" except that there is no way to decide whether a given formula $\varphi_m$ is true for $x$.

Comment: You define $\varphi_p$ in terms of $\varphi_m$?

Comment: Your attempt at formalising the statement doesn't refer to the lengths of the formulas in any way (to do this you have to use a metatheory to model syntax, which is how we resolve the apparentt paradox). Also $\varphi_m(x) \wedge \neg\exists y\in\mathbb{N}(\varphi_m(y))$ is identically false, which probably isn't what you intended. Bear in mind that your argument has to deal with formulas like $\psi_n(x) {:=} x = S^n(0)$ that do define the successive natural numbers.

Comment: @RobArthan Forgive me for being ignorant about anything logic or model theory, after all it's just a random thought; but I cannot quite understand what you mean. I didn't make any reference to the lengths of the formulas. And for the $\neg\exists y\in\mathbb{N}(\varphi_m(y))$ part: I have a condition $y<x$.

Comment: You say you are trying to model the paradox mathematically, but the paradox talks about the length of a formula, while your mathematical model doesn't. Your condition $y < x$, doesn't affect the fact that $\phi_m(x)$ and $\lnot\exists y \in \Bbb{N}(\phi_m(y)))$ are mutually contradictory unless $x \not\in \Bbb{N}$.